# QUdpSocket pyqt qt

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Hi hope someone can help me out i'm writing a small gui that will graph data sent via a UDP Socket.  I decided to to this with QUdpSocket from PyQt.  I used the the example code (which i used to test my server) and then stripped the gui.

```
from PyQt4 import QtNetwork


class graphUDP(QtNetwork.QUdpSocket):


def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(graphUDP, self).__init__(parent)

    self.udpSocket = QtNetwork.QUdpSocket(self)
    self.udpSocket.bind(8888)

    self.udpSocket.readyRead.connect(self.processPendingDatagrams)

    print "All ok line 20"

def processPendingDatagrams(self):
    print "line 23 All ok"

    while self.udpSocket.hasPendingDatagrams():
        datagram, host, port = self.udpSocket.readDatagram(self.udpSocket.pendingDatagramSize())

        print "All ok line 28"
        print datagram

if __name__ == '__main__':

import sys
graphRun = graphUDP()
graphRun
```

I put some debugging lines in to see what was happening it looks like the class gets instantiated but the signal and slot doesn't connect to fire off the function.  I'm out of my depth and running round in circles any ideas/pointers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why do you extend QUdpSocket, and then instantiate a new QUdpSocket in your constructor? That doesn't really make any sense.

First decide how to create your class and how to instantiate it.

Besides that I can't see any problem on why it doesn't work.

Also, your alignment on the bottom "main" part is wrong. And usually QT requires you to create  a QApplication before you can use any other QT class.

Comment: Sorry a maybe a little confused i'm new at this.  I thought in PyQt the thing to do was inherit from the parent class and use the super method to modify the inherited class.

Comment: You use the super method and then you do this:     self.udpSocket = QtNetwork.QUdpSocket(self), creating another socket.